# Chrome Extension SidePanel: Limit sidepanel to specific URLs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm developing a chrome extension that lives in the sidePanel.
I want to display the sidePanel only for specific website (like google.com) and disable it for all the rest.

In the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/sidePanel#by-site) I found this snippet but it required the `tabs` permission.

```
// service-worker.js

const GOOGLE_ORIGIN = 'https://www.google.com';

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (!tab.url) return;
  const url = new URL(tab.url);
  // Enables the side panel on google.com
  if (url.origin === GOOGLE_ORIGIN) {
    await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
      tabId,
      path: 'sidepanel.html',
      enabled: true
    });
  } else {
    // Disables the side panel on all other sites
    await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
      tabId,
      enabled: false
    });
  }
});
```

Is there a way to achieve the same only using `activeTab` permission?

Comment: No. The activeTab permission requires explicit user action to invoke the extension. You can suggest adding "matches" to "side_panel" section in manifest.json in [WECG](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/) and/or https://crbug.com.

Comment: That's disappointing :(
Is there no workaround with getting the URL from content scripts or something like that?

Comment: Declaring a content script adds host permissions so the extension will have an installation warning that it can read and modify data on that site. If that's okay, you can simply use `host_permissions` and chrome.tabs.onUpdated without the content script.